# Check if AD Group is Member of another group (recursive)

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

Imagine i have structure

```cs
RootGroup <- Group{x} .... <- Group{x+n} <- Group100
```

How could I check that `Group100` is member of `RootGroup`

I have this and it returns always `false`

```cs
private bool IsMemberOfInternal(string userOrGroupDistinguishedName, string groupMembershipDistinguishedName)
        {
            GroupPrincipal principal = null;
            GroupPrincipal target = null;
            try
            {
                principal = _getUserGroupPrincipalFunc(principalContext, userOrGroupDistinguishedName);
                target = _getUserGroupPrincipalFunc(principalContext, groupMembershipDistinguishedName);

                if (principal != default(GroupPrincipal)
                    && target != default(GroupPrincipal))
                {
                    return principal.IsMemberOf(target);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off not using `GroupPrincipal` for this. AD actually has a built-in way to do this kind of search that is far faster than any thing `GroupPrincipal` can do. You can use that by using `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` directly (that's what `GroupPrincipal` and `PrincipalSearcher` use behind the scenes anyway).

I wrote an article about figuring out if a *user* is a member of a specific group, but it applies just the same to groups. I have a [sample method](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/09/13/one-user-is-member-of-a-group.html#the-slightly-harder-but-still-easy-way) there that you can use for this:

```
private static bool IsUserInGroup(DirectoryEntry user, DirectoryEntry group, bool recursive) {

    //fetch the attributes we're going to need
    user.RefreshCache(new [] {"distinguishedName", "objectSid"});
    group.RefreshCache(new [] {"distinguishedName", "groupType"});

    //This magic number tells AD to look for the user recursively through any nested groups
    var recursiveFilter = recursive ? ":1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:" : "";

    var userDn = (string) user.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;
    var groupDn = (string) group.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;

    var filter = $"(member{recursiveFilter}={userDn})";

    if (((int) group.Properties["groupType"].Value & 8) == 0) {
        var groupDomainDn = groupDn.Substring(
            groupDn.IndexOf(",DC=", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        var userDomainDn = userDn.Substring(
            userDn.IndexOf(",DC=", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        if (groupDomainDn != userDomainDn) {
            //It's a Domain Local group, and the user and group are on
            //different domains, so the account might show up as a Foreign
            //Security Principal. So construct a list of SID's that could
            //appear in the group for this user
            var fspFilters = new StringBuilder();

            var userSid =
                new SecurityIdentifier((byte[]) user.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
            fspFilters.Append(
                $"(member{recursiveFilter}=CN={userSid},CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals{groupDomainDn})");

            if (recursive) {
                //Any of the groups the user is in could show up as an FSP,
                //so we need to check for them all
                user.RefreshCache(new [] {"tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal"});
                var tokenGroups = user.Properties["tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal"];
                foreach (byte[] token in tokenGroups) {
                    var groupSid = new SecurityIdentifier(token, 0);
                    fspFilters.Append(
                        $"(member{recursiveFilter}=CN={groupSid},CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals{groupDomainDn})");
                }
            }
            filter = $"(|{filter}{fspFilters})";
        }
    }

    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher {
        Filter = filter,
        SearchRoot = group,
        PageSize = 1, //we're only looking for one object
        SearchScope = SearchScope.Base
    };

    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn"); //just so it doesn't load every property

    return searcher.FindOne() != null;
}
```

This method also handles the case where the `user` (or your child group) is on an external trusted domain from the root group. That may or may not be a thing you have to worry about.

Just pass a `DirectoryEntry` for your `Group100` as the `user` parameter. Something like this:

```
var isMemberOf = IsUserInGroup(
    new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{userOrGroupDistinguishedName}"),
    new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{groupMembershipDistinguishedName}"),
    true);
```

For recursive searches (when you pass `true` for the `recursive` parameter), it uses the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` "matching rule OID" (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax)):

> This rule is limited to filters that apply to the DN. This is a special "extended" match operator that walks the chain of ancestry in objects all the way to the root until it finds a match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... where can i find some documentation about  these magic strings like `:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:`

Comment: Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax (search the page for "LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN")